# Django account_activation_token.check_token always return False in constant_time_compare()

Tags: python, django, token

I have an `ActivationTokenGenerator` that create a token that will be used for account verification that will be send by email. For example I configured it like this with parameters including timestamp, id, and user active status:

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils import six


    class ActivationTokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):

        def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
            return six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) + six.text_type(user.is_active)


    account_activation_token = ActivationTokenGenerator()
```

Then I use the `account_activation_token` for generating token in a verification email I sent with a `send_mail`.

```
@classmethod
    def send_email(cls, request, user):
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        mail_subject = 'Activate your Poros account.'
        message = render_to_string('email_verification.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        to_email = user.email
        email = EmailMessage(
            mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
        )
        email.send()
```

Everything looks perfect email sent with a token that included inside a url with pattern like this:

```
url(r'activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        activate, name='activate'),
```

and looks like this in the email:

```
http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

then when the link clicked it will call this `activate` view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.contrib.auth import login

from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_decode
from accounts.utilities import account_activation_token
from accounts.models import User


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        id = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        print(id)
        user = User.objects.get(pk=id)
        print(user)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    print(token)

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

But the `activate` view always return activation link is invalid. I tried to track it down into the `account_activation_token.check_token(user, token)`

I tried to go deeper and debug Inside the Django `PasswordResetTokenGenerator` I found the `check_token()` has step to check the timestamp/uid with a line like this:

```
# Check that the timestamp/uid has not been tampered with
    if not constant_time_compare(self._make_token_with_timestamp(user, ts), token):
        return False
```

which called `constant_time_compare`:

```
def constant_time_compare(val1, val2):
    """Return True if the two strings are equal, False otherwise."""
    return hmac.compare_digest(force_bytes(val1), force_bytes(val2))
```

I don't really understand what's going on in the lower level of this `token_check`. What is the better approach to solve this?

Answer (score 8):

Change this line in :

```
return six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) + six.text_type(user.is_active)
```

to this line:

```
return six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) + six.text_type(user.username)
```

And it works. I workaround with this method. But don't know the cause.

Comment: Did anyone ever get a better understanding of why this is/isn't a good solution? I don't feel comfortable changing security related code just because "it works"

Comment: I wonder because user.is_active is a boolean? I have a local environment (django inside docker) that the original line works, but my production environment (django inside dokku) it does not work. Changing is_active to username seems to have fixed this.

Comment: Doug Smith is correct about the is_active function. When you use the `make_token` function, the `user` you pass as a parameter is the user you created directly from the model and you set `is_active = False`. After clicking the link to activate your email, the piece of code `user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)` retrieves the user from the database and `user.is_active` is 0.

Within `_make_hash_value`, which is called twice (once from `make_token` and once from `check_token`), `six.text_type(False)` and `six.text_type(0)` are different which results in unequal tokens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you verify if form is valid and set the value of  user.is_active, you have to set it to 0 and not to False, because when you call activate function, it passes the value of user.is_active from db and it's 0 or 1 (not True or False).

Answer (score 0):

The `is_active` (0 and False being different) problem has already been covered and answered. Another problem is within

```
url(r'activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        activate, name='activate'),
```

When you click on email activation link, if a parameter is longer than permitted size, that parameter will be truncated. In my case, the token was too long and therefore, I increased it from `{1,20}` to `{1,40}`. After a lot of frustration, this turned out to the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem in your code is getting the user id.
so, you must change "user = User.objects.get(pk=id)" to user = User.objects.get(pk=uid) and check it.